# Short echo Tag PHP Variables and Methods

Tags: php

I've been using the PHP short echo code but realised that it doesn't print out the return value from a method.  That is, the following will work

```
<?= $my_variable ?>
<?php echo $my_object->get_value(); ?>
```

But this won't return anything

```
<?= $my_object->get_value() ?>
```

Why does calling a method that returns a value not print to the screen with the short hand?

Comment: This does actually work. Share your get_value() function with us. Edit: There is no difference between echo and <?=.

Comment: @evayly you're right, not sure what I did wrong before but it's working now :)  It's one of those days when I've spent too long looking at the screen!

Answer (score 5):

In normal cases, it should work.

See and test:

```
<?php 
    class A {
        public function a() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    $a = new A;

    ?>

    <?= $a->a() ?>
```

output: `1`

So, I think your problem come with the `get_value()` method, it seems that the method does not return a printable value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had a syntax error it's working as expected now :)

Comment: :D It's nice! So, there is no real problem here!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like not well tested code. You may run this code (may be in [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/))

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public function getValue() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

$my_object = new MyClass();
?>

<?= $my_object->getValue() ?>
```

and see that it outputs "Hello"

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had a syntax error it's working as expected now :)

Answer (score 2):

The `<?=` is shortcode for `<?php echo` so it should in the same way. Please show use the code of the `get_value()` method. Maybe there it does return empty string or null :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had a syntax error it's working as expected now :)